# Intrinsic proof for $(I + AB)^{-1}A = A(I + BA)^{-1}$ by using Schur complements on matrix block elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $(I + B(I - AB)^{-1}A)$ to be inverse of $(I + BA)$, how could we derive that the following alternative form holds

$(I + AB)^{-1}A = A(I + BA)^{-1}$.

This is easy to verify(direct proof). But I would like to have a more "intrinsic" proof or proof from "scratch". e.g. How probably use Woodbury  inverse formula, or $(I + B(I - AB)^{-1}A) = (I + BA)^{-1}$ to derive it ?

-------------------------------------------------Update-----------------------------------------------------------

Now I am coming up with another proof which I feel more comfortable.

Proof:
By applying matrix block elimination, i.e. $Mx = b$ to be partitioned as $$\begin{pmatrix} A & B\\ C & D \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{pmatrix}$$ where $A, D$ are smaller square matrices and nonsingular, with two alternative forms of schur complements, we can obtain
$$(A + BD^{-1}C)^{-1}BD^{-1} = A^{-1}B(D + CA^{-1}B)^{-1}$$. Then by setting $A, D$ to be $I$, $B$ to be $A$, $C$ to be $B$, then it comes out the result $$(I + AB)^{-1}A = A(I + BA)^{-1}$$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @πr8's idea, I'm now writing down the complete proof here.

Given $A + ABA = A(I + BA) = (I + AB)A$, we can obtain $(I + AB) = A(I + BA)A^{-1}$, by applying inverse rule on matrix multiplication, it follows $$(I + AB)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^{-1}(I + BA)^{-1}A^{-1} = A(I + BA)^{-1}A^{-1}$$ which implies $(I + AB)^{-1}A = A(I + BA)^{-1}$.

Comment: This requires $A$ to be invertible.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Now I updated a new proof on the question description, could you help me to take a look if it makes stronger sense than this proof here ? And it does not require $A$ to be invertible.

Comment: This again requires $A$ to be invertible :(

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the "suppose we know" part, multiply from the left by $(I + AB)$, from the right by $(I + BA)$, cancel inverses, expand the brackets and see that you get the same thing on both sides of the $=$-sign.

Comment: I think it's difficult to use the inverse formula, simply because if you do, then one side has a term that contains $(I-AB)^{-1}$ and the other side contains $(I-BA)^{-1}$, so you're basically back where you started.

Comment: Or is there someway to derive it from scratch ?

Comment: @Xingdong $A(I+BA)=A+ABA=(I+AB)A$ is the core observation, you then take inverses as required to wrap things up.

Comment: @πr8 Thank you so much for the idea ! Now I am convinced with the identity itself.